# Showing different WifiP2pDevice device name in android

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am using Moto g4 plus device. And developing mobile application using WifiP2P API. Everything is working fine but In my device i have getting different name.
So i want to know where i can find that name in android device. Please help me.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Information is insufficient in your question. Firstly add your relevant code whatever you have tried. Secondly clearly mention your expected outcome and current result. Otherwise people will find your question boring, they will either ignore it or close it. Finally delete it.

Comment: Thank you VicJordan, For replying my question. Actually my question was where to find Wifi Direct device name in android device. and I got the solution that, In setting of WiFi we can get the name of Wifi Direct device .